# Flutter - image drop shadow effect

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an app concept and as I was creating a wireframe and photoshop template I was wondering if this effect is recreateable using flutter.

Instead of taking a solid color I'd like to use the colors from the image instead. Does this effect have a certain name?

In this example the left area of the shadow stays beige, while the right side looks pink.

[image: image shadow]

Answer (score 7):

Recently I made [drop_shadow_image](https://pub.dev/packages/drop_shadow_image) package on flutter for the drop shadow you can take a look at the implementation below.
also you can find the link to GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/saquibansari0101/drop_shadow_image).

#### Installation

1. Add this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  drop_shadow_image: ^0.9.0
```

2. Import the package into your dart file:

```dart
import 'package:drop_shadow_image/drop_shadow_image.dart';
```

#### Example

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:drop_shadow_image/drop_shadow_lib.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body:
        Center(
          child: DropShadowImage(
            offset: Offset(10,10),
            scale: 1,
            blurRadius: 12,
            borderRadius: 20,
            image: Image.asset('assets/cat.png',
            width: 300,),
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Properties of the class

```dart
1. Key key
 
2. double scale  // Size to parent. 

3. Offset offset  // Position of shadow. (dx) for horizontal displacement (dy) for vertical displacement.

4. double blurRadius // Amount of blur in the shadow. 0 means no blur.

5. double borderRadius //  border radius of image

6. Image image (@required) // The image.
```

#### Screenshot

[image]